# Empty data set when querying all streets in different districts with OverpassTurbo

Tags: overpass-turbo

I would like to query all roads in different level 5 boundaries. I query with the relation nodes, because the spelling of the district names is not consistent. I get an empty record back every time. I have already checked the relation numbers several times.

```
[out:json];
(
  rel(10696636); // Chinsali
  rel(10676858);   // Chitambo
  rel(10695331);  // Isoka
  rel(14473488);  // Kanchibiya
  rel(14473552);  // Lavushimanda
  rel(10677069);  // Mpika
  rel(10696889);   // Nakonde
  rel(10676516);   // Serenje
  rel(10696555);  // Shiwa Ng'andu
)->.searchArea;
way["highway"](area.searchArea);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Does anyone have an idea where the error is?